# Excel - Skip Blank Table Cells Formula

Tags: excel

I have a table being created via an XML map so it has a lot of blank cells in each column. It looks like:

```
| Name | Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Stat 3|
| Test |        |        |       |
|      |  Four  |        |       |
|      |        |   5    |       |
|      |        |        |  102  |
```

Basically each row has only one value and I am trying to transpose it onto another worksheet where all the values are one row like this:

```
| Name | Stat 1 | Stat 2 | Stat 3 |
| Test |   Four |    5   |   102  |
```

In my searching I found this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table9[@name],SMALL(IF(Table9[@name]<>"",ROW(Table9[@name])-ROW(Table9[@name])+1),ROWS(A2))),"")
```

I set that and in A1 of another sheet and drag it down and it does return the populated cells but it is also returning `0` for all the blank cells instead of skipping them until it has a value to return.

There may be a better way to do this so I am open to other options but would prefer to avoid vba if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: please note you should have better XML mapping in the first place, but if you care about excel formulas to compress every 4 rows of your input into 1 proper row of output, see my answer.

Comment: @deathApril How should I have better XML mapping? I can't control the layout of the xml file. I just used Excel's built in method of dragging the elements to the column headers and this is the output I got. It seems simpler than writing an XSD from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say input sheet is called `Sheet1` and the `Name` is in cell A1 on both sheets. Then use following formula for `Name` on output sheet:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW()-2)*4+2)
```

and for `Stat 1`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,(ROW()-2)*4+3)
```

and so on ... more generally:

```
=INDEX(
  input_column_range,
  (ROW()-first_row_in_output)*number_of_columns + first_row_in_input+column_index
)
```